# How can I get IP of a specific hop for traceroute in python

Tags: python, scapy, traceroute

```
addr = socket.gethostbyname('dalitstan.org')
target = [addr]
result, unans = traceroute(target,maxttl=32)
```

I am doing this and getting the below output. Is there some way here to get the IP of specific hop in a variable. And also why some hop number are missing in the traceroute result?

```
Begin emission:
Finished to send 32 packets.
*************************
Received 25 packets, got 25 answers, remaining 7 packets
   185.53.178.6:tcp80 
1  192.168.43.1    11 
3  10.71.83.18     11 
4  172.16.26.245   11 
5  172.26.31.242   11 
11 49.44.18.38     11 
13 103.198.140.164 11 
14 103.198.140.27  11 
15 80.81.194.27    11 
16 217.64.161.25   11 
17 217.64.170.214  11 
18 185.53.178.6    SA 
19 185.53.178.6    SA 
20 185.53.178.6    SA 
21 185.53.178.6    SA 
22 185.53.178.6    SA 
23 185.53.178.6    SA 
24 185.53.178.6    SA 
25 185.53.178.6    SA 
26 185.53.178.6    SA 
27 185.53.178.6    SA 
28 185.53.178.6    SA 
29 185.53.178.6    SA 
30 185.53.178.6    SA 
31 185.53.178.6    SA 
32 185.53.178.6    SA
```

On trying `result.get_trace()['185.53.178.6'][7]` I am getting below error. What may be the issue.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cens2.py", line 16, in <module>
    print result.get_trace()['185.53.178.6'][7]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/layers/inet.py", line 1040, in get_trace
    m = min(x for x, y in k.itervalues() if y[1])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/layers/inet.py", line 1040, in <genexpr>
    m = min(x for x, y in k.itervalues() if y[1])
TypeError: 'bool' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: `traceroute()` from scapy returns an object that apparently has all this information within it. scapy's documentation doesn't have details on it, but you can pretty print the object to see its structure. The hops should be there as well as some clue about the missing hops.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the value for a hop using result.get_trace()
So for hop 7 use result.get_trace()['185.53.178.6'][7]

```
    >>> result.get_trace()['185.53.178.6'][7]
    ('203.50.6.93', False)

    or 

    >>> result.get_trace()['185.53.178.6'][7][0]
    '203.50.6.93'
    >>> something = result.get_trace()['185.53.178.6'][7][0]
    >>> something
    '203.50.6.93'
```

Some index checking from a different trace shown as.

```
    >>> result.get_trace()['161.0.97.141'].keys()
    dict_keys([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20])

    ^^^^ missing hop 13 ^^^^ (Same as your hop 7)


    >>> for item in result.get_trace()['161.0.97.141'].keys():
    >>> print('Row number ' + str(item) + ' hop IP is : ' + result.get_trace()['161.0.97.141'][item][0])

    Row number 1 hop IP is : 10.0.0.138
    Row number 2 hop IP is : 10.218.192.1
    Row number 3 hop IP is : 58.160.250.129
    Row number 4 hop IP is : 203.50.44.36
    Row number 5 hop IP is : 203.50.11.136
    Row number 6 hop IP is : 203.50.11.180
    Row number 7 hop IP is : 203.50.6.93
    Row number 8 hop IP is : 203.50.13.98
    Row number 9 hop IP is : 202.84.222.62
    Row number 10 hop IP is : 202.84.136.209
    Row number 11 hop IP is : 202.84.253.86
    Row number 12 hop IP is : 134.159.61.46
    <<<  no hop 13 shown >>>
    Row number 14 hop IP is : 4.59.90.110
    Row number 15 hop IP is : 63.245.106.96
    Row number 16 hop IP is : 63.245.5.100
    Row number 17 hop IP is : 63.245.79.85
    Row number 18 hop IP is : 190.242.166.37
    Row number 19 hop IP is : 190.112.224.132
    Row number 20 hop IP is : 161.0.97.141
```

Comment: I also expect you can get the missing hops details from checking 'unans'

Comment: I am getting some error while trying this. I have updated the question with the error. Can you help me with the error ?

Comment: I tried in Python 3.5.2 and scapy-python3==0.21 and could not reproduce
>>> import scapy
>>> from scapy.all import *
I expect it may be related to the versions you are using coupled with an index error. I have added to my response the checking of index for reference.