# Scapy: Indexing traceroute result with get_trace() method returns TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, scapy

I would like to run traceroute with scapy and index the returned traceroute results using the get_results() method (I am using [this StackExchange post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45777867/how-can-i-get-ip-of-a-specific-hop-for-traceroute-in-python) as reference).

However, when printing the dictionary keys, I am getting a TypeError when attempting to print the keys using the following code:

```
from scapy.all import *

target = '52.54.2.173'
result, unans = traceroute(target)

print(result.get_trace().keys())
```

Here is the error output (unorderable types):

```
File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(result.get_trace().keys())
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scapy/layers/inet.py", line 1090, in get_trace
    if l > m:
TypeError: unorderable types: int() > str()
```

After looking at the scapy source code [here](https://bitbucket.org/secdev/scapy/src/cd8f482c8858e940959bf9c6c03a8d336db0edaf/scapy/layers/inet.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#inet.py-1295) I could still not figure out how I should be calling get_trace() to avoid this error. Am I not understanding somthing fundamental about scapys traceroute/TracerouteResults class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an old scapy version. (BTW we switched from Bitbucket to github in 2016)

Try again using the latest dev version: https://github.com/secdev/scapy/archive/master.zip

Then install it with (sudo) `python setup.py install`

It works:

[image: Traceroute.get_results()]